# Apple like shaking icons in UICollectionView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to develop an app in which the items should be displayed as the `UICollectionView`. When user tap & hold the items all the items should start shaking like the Apple home screen on which icons start to shake when we want to delete an app. So please tell me how can I implement this feature. Is there any library can use?

Comment: How about doing some programming?

Comment: I don't know how do i code it so that is why i asked it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Declare your variables first:

```
UIButton* _deleteButton;
CGPoint p;  // It is a point which will give you which cell has been selected.
```

Add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

In `.m` file, in `viewDidLoad`, add `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `collectionView`, since you want to shake the cells at long press:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Add gesture recognizer to your collection view cell
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr
    = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = .3; // To detect after how many seconds you want shake the cells
    lpgr.delegate = self;
    [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

    lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;

    /// This will be helpful to restore the animation when clicked outside the cell
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    //lpgr.minimumPressDuration = .3; //seconds
    tap.delegate = self;
    [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}
```

You can now implement `handleLongPress:` in your `.m` file. When you will long press your `collectionViewCell`, you will get (x,y) co-ordinates of where the user has pressed the cell, which we will store in point `p`.

Based on that point, you will be able to fetch the appropriate `indexPath` of the appropriate cell.

```
p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collectionView]; // Store (x,y) co-ordinate where the user has tapped the cell in point p.

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
```

Now, give animation to the cell, which has been tapped using `CABasicAnimation` of `QuartzCore` framework. At the time of animation, bring your `_deleteButton` up so that it is visible.

With `handleTap:`, you will then be able to restore animation when clicked outside of the `collectionViewCell`.

```
-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"singleTap");
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        return;
    }
    p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collectionView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil){
        NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"no" forKey:@"longPressed"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"singleTap"];
        //_deleteButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        //[cell addSubview:_deleteButton];
        //[_deleteButton removeFromSuperview];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];

    } else {

    }

}
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        return;
    }
    p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collectionView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil){
        NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
    } else {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"longPressed"];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];

    }
}
```

Based on the selected item, delete the appropriate item.

```
-(void)deleteyourItem
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    //delete your item based on the `indexpath` from your collectionViewArray here.
    //OR If you are accessing the database to display the collectionView, you can compare the value fetched based on the `indexPath`, with your database value and then delete it.

    // Reload your collectionView after deletion
}
```

After you reload the collection view, `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, will look like this:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"favoritecell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   // UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]init];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:251.0/255.0 green:144.0/255.0 blue:13.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];


    //img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];

    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);


    if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"longPressed"] isEqualToString:@"yes"])
    {
        CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
        [anim setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
        [anim setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI/64]];
        [anim setDuration:0.1];
        [anim setRepeatCount:NSUIntegerMax];
        [anim setAutoreverses:YES];
        cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        [cell.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"SpringboardShake"];
        CGFloat delButtonSize = 75;

        _deleteButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, delButtonSize, delButtonSize)];
        _deleteButton.center = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        _deleteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [_deleteButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell addSubview:_deleteButton];

        [_deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteRecipe) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }

    else if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"singleTap"] isEqualToString:@"yes"])
    {

        for(UIView *subview in [cell subviews]) {
            if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                [subview removeFromSuperview];
            } else {
                // Do nothing - not a UIButton or subclass instance
            }
        }
            [cell.layer removeAllAnimations];
//            _deleteButton.hidden = YES;
//            [_deleteButton removeFromSuperview];


    }

    //251, 144 , 13


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Don't just post a bunch of code. Add some explanation too.

Comment: Wait a min man, editing it

Comment: Variable declarations should usually go in a .m file, so that you don't end up redeclaring the same variables if you include the .h file in more than one file.

Comment: @Caleb thanks for your advise, will take care!!

Comment: How can i put cell to normal mode when pressed outside the collection view?

Comment: @deepakkumar I have updated my answer. Changed handleLongPress: method and added didSelectItemAtIndexPath: to handle the animations.

Comment: have you tried running it?

Comment: Yes, I am currently using in one of my app!

Comment: well how do i stop deletion mode by just clicking outside of cell not on any existing cell.

Comment: your code works fine as of now it just animate single cell but i need to animate all the cells not a single how can i do that?

Comment: are you there ?@RoOmin

Comment: I will come back to you tomorrow.... off the work...:p

Comment: Hello,are you there @RoOmin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94468/discussion-between-roomin-and-deepak-kumar).